# ¿Como soluciono el error MySQL ha dicho: #1055 al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

estoy ejecutando un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, estoy usando PHPMyAdmin, pero sale este error

```
MySQL ha dicho: #1055 - Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Siscopevw.tmpDetNomina.Mes' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

He investigado y hay que cambiar las variables de sql_mode, sin embargo, ya lo hice y el error persiste, incluso he dejado vacía esa variable y sigue existiendo el mismo error

[image]

Adjunto tambien la captura del mensaje de error, en verdad ya no sé qué intentar llevo atorado con esto ya varias horas, gracias de antemano

Comment: No, no cambies `sql_mode`, más bien arregla tu consulta, porque no es conforme al estándar SQL. El problema es que MySQL es demasiado permisivo con esto, pero puede que rectifique en un futuro dejando tu código inútil. Simplemente, en una consulta con `GROUP BY` debes indicar qué hacer con todos los resultados que puedan ser duplicados: o agregas esas columnas a la lista del grupo, o las pones dentro de una función de agregación: `MIN`, `MAX`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, etc.

Comment: La cuestion es que en el desarrollo local, me permitia efectuar la consulta sin problemas, cuando la migre al servidor empezo a salir ese error

Comment: Sí, eso es porque MySQL te permite *apagar* el `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, pero eso no está bien realmente, esas consultas no son conformes al estándar SQL. Si un día tu código se migra a otra BD no funcionará y puede que el mismo MySQL rectifique en el futuro y tu código quede inservible.